# Shiny Bookmarking Issue with RenderUI

Tags: r, shiny, bookmarks

I have written this code in order to bookmark inputs from dynamically created elements.

As you can see i have managed to do it with the first table (output$othertable) but  no with the output$ratings. Is this because of the renderUI?

I found this https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/2139 so i installed the latest [package](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/NEWS.md) in order to overcome this.

Unfortunately this was not the solution.

Any ideas??

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmlwidgets) 
library(data.table) 

ui <- function(request){dashboardPage(

  skin="blue",

  dashboardHeader(
    title="sth",
    titleWidth = 300),

  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 300,
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        "Gathering Information",
        tabName = "gatheringinformation",
        icon=icon("github")
      )
      )),


  dashboardBody(

      tabItem(tabName = "gatheringinformation",
              h2("Gathering Information"),

              bookmarkButton(),
              fluidRow(
                box(
                  width = 4, 
                  title = "Inputs",
                  status= "primary",
                  solidHeader = TRUE,
                  h5("Please specify the number of alternatives, criteria and experts"),

                  numericInput("alternatives", h3("Alternatives"), 
                               value = "1"),
                  numericInput("criteria", h3("Criteria"), 
                               value = "1"),
                  numericInput("experts", h3("Experts"), 
                               value = "1")  
                ),

      box(title = "Alternatives", 
          width = 4,
          status = "primary", 
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsible = TRUE,
          div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll'),
          splitLayout(tableOutput("othertable"))

      ),

      box(title = "View Data", 
          width = 12,
          status = "primary", 
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsible = TRUE,
          div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll'),
          splitLayout(uiOutput("ratings"))

      ))


                        )))}
              ####################################
              ############   SERVER   ############
              ####################################

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  onBookmark(function(state) {
    for (i in 1:input$alternatives){
      state$values$alternativestable[i] <- input[[paste0("data_alternatives_r",i,"c1")]]}
    for (i in 1:input$criteria){
      state$values$criteriatable[i] <- input[[paste0("data_criteria_r",i,"c1")]]}

    someData <- rep(NaN, input$alternatives*input$criteria*input$experts);  
    state$values$viewdatatable<-array(someData, c(input$alternatives, input$criteria, input$experts))

    for (i in 1:input$experts){
      for (m in 1:input$criteria){
        for (n in 1:input$alternatives){
          state$values$viewdatatable[n,m,i] <- input[[paste0("t",i,"r",n,"c",m)]]
          l<-state$values$viewdatatable[n,m,i]<-input[[paste0("t1r1c1")]]
        }}
    }
  })

  onRestore(function(state) {

    for (i in 1:input$alternatives){
      Y <- state$values$alternativestable[i]
      updateNumericInput(session, paste0("data_alternatives_r",i,"c1"), value = Y)
    }

    for (i in 1:input$experts){
      for (m in 1:input$criteria){
        for (n in 1:input$alternatives){
          Y <- state$values$viewdatatable[n,m,i]
          updateNumericInput(session, paste0("t",i,"r",n,"c",m), value = Y)

        }}}



  })

  isolate({
    output$othertable <- 
      renderTable({
        text.inputs.col1 <- paste0("<input id='data_alternatives_r", 1:input$alternatives, "c", 1, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='text' value=''>")
        df_data_alternatives <- data.frame(text.inputs.col1)
        colnames(df_data_alternatives) <- paste0("Alternatives")
        df_data_alternatives
      },sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)})
  isolate({
  output$ratings <- renderUI({lapply(1:input$experts,function(j){
    renderTable({
      num.inputs.col1 <- paste0("<input id='t",j, "r", 1:input$alternatives, "c", 1, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='number' value='1'>")
      #num.inputs.col2 <- paste0("<input id='t",j, "r", 1:input$alternatives, "c", 2, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='number' value='1'>")
      df <- data.frame(num.inputs.col1)
      if (input$criteria >= 2){
        for (i in 2:input$criteria){
          num.inputs.coli <- paste0("<input id='t",j, "r", 1:input$alternatives, "c", i, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='number' value='1'>")
          df <- cbind(df,num.inputs.coli)
        }
      }
      colnames(df) <- paste0("Criteria ",as.numeric(1:input$criteria))
      rownames(df) <- paste0("Alternative ",as.numeric(1:input$alternatives))
      df
    },align = 'c',rownames = TRUE,caption = paste("Expert " ,j), caption.placement = getOption("xtable.caption.placement", "top"), sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)})})
})
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server,enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing I found that delaying the call to `updateNumericInput` did the trick. The `numericInput` elements are apparently not rendered by the time the corresponding `update` function is called. This means that part of the `state` will be lost.

I used `shinyjs::delay` around the `onRestore` callback function that restores the ui based on the state. The callback will wait for 200 milliseconds before firing `updateNumericInput`

```
## in server - onRestore
shinyjs::delay(200, {

  for (i in 1:input$experts){
    for (m in 1:input$criteria){
      for (n in 1:input$alternatives){
        Y <- state$values$viewdatatable[n,m,i]
        updateNumericInput(session, paste0("t",i,"r",n,"c",m), value = Y)

      }}}
})
```

It seems this gives `renderUI` enough time to render the table before `updateNumericInput`gets called. If you rty to apply this fix, don't forget to use `shinyjs::useShinyjs()` somewhere in the ui.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much!